# How to create embeddedings for a column that is a list of categorical values

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am having some trouble deciding how to create embeddings for a categorical feature for my DNN model. The feature consists of a non fixed set of tags.

The feature is like:

```
column = [['Adventure','Animation','Comedy'],
          ['Adventure','Comedy'],
          ['Adventure','Children','Comedy']
```

I would like to do this with `tensorflow` so I know the [tf.feature_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column) module should work, I just don't know which version to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to fill in your features to the same length.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

column = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*column, fillvalue='UNK'))).T
print(column)

[['Adventure' 'Animation' 'Comedy']
 ['Adventure' 'Comedy' 'UNK']
 ['Adventure' 'Children' 'Comedy']]
```

Then you can use [`tf.feature_column.embedding_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column) to create embeddings for a categorical feature. The inputs of `embedding_column` must be a `CategoricalColumn` created by any of the `categorical_column_*` function.

```
# if you have big vocabulary list in files, you can use tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file
cat_fc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    'cat_data', # identifying the input feature
    ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Children'], # vocabulary list
    dtype=tf.string,
    default_value=-1)

cat_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
    categorical_column =cat_fc,
    dimension = 5,
    combiner='mean')
```

`categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` will ignore the `'UNK'` since there is no `'UNK'` in vocabulary list. `dimension` specifying dimension of the embedding and `combiner` specifying how to reduce if there are multiple entries in a single row with 'mean' the default in `embedding_column`.

The result:

```
tensor = tf.feature_column.input_layer({'cat_data':column}, [cat_column])

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    print(session.run(tensor))

[[-0.694761   -0.0711766   0.05720187  0.01770079 -0.09884425]
 [-0.8362482   0.11640486 -0.01767573 -0.00548441 -0.05738768]
 [-0.71162754 -0.03012567  0.15568805  0.00752804 -0.1422816 ]]
```